# How to call java FTP upload file in angular JS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ftp, javapoly

I trying to do (FTP) file upload /download using angular JS but could not found anything upon searching .
So finally i end up calling JAVA ftp upload inside angular JS code which is not working and throwing error .

I have tried to use javaPolly.js which downloads JVM inside the browser and then that can execute java code .
My java code (ftp upload/download ) is working when i run it alone without angular js also my sample java code is also working inside angular js but only when i call java ftp upload inside the angular js i get problem

```
<h1>Hi</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.javapoly.com/javapoly.js"></script>
<!--
-->
<script type="text/java" src="commons-net-3.0.1.jar"></script>
 <script type="text/java">
package com.demo;
import com.javapoly.dom.Window;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
  public class Greeter
  {

    public static void uploadFile() 
    {
   try{
          FTPClient ftp= new FTPClient();
                              ftp.connect("::565:a77:861f");
                              ftp.login("db", "lotus-2004");
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                              ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("Downloaded");
                              reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
                              ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        File f=new File(localFileFullName);
                              ftpUploader.uploadFile("C:\\suda\\temp.txt");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);
        this.ftp.storeFile(f.getName(),input)

    }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
  }
</script>
        <script >
            com.demo.Greeter.uploadFile();
</script>
```

When i run above code i get below error

```
 VM27:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Websock is not defined
    at e.a.socketCreate(Z)V [as code] (eval at t.evalNativeModule     (https://www.javapoly.com/doppio/doppio.js:1:12735),
```

How do i upload file using this ?Or is there anyway to upload file using FTP in angular js itself .

Comment: i don't believe you can use javascript (javapoly) to access the local environment, the browsers run on a sandbox environment, there is no direct access to file system without user involvement

Comment: @DevZer0 so you are saying we can not do this this way ?If not is there anyway i can proceed ?

Comment: your code to me suggest that you are targeting a specific file in your local environment. what i would do is, to allow the user to select a particular file they like either using pure java-script triggered "file input" and then send the data to the server with use some type of form submission, or websocket